# HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Ao tentar chamar um metodo do Controller esta retornando o erro abaixo:

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request Type Status Report
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
>   something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.53

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ManterFuncionarioController {

@RequestMapping("CriarFuncionario")
    public String criarFuncionario(Model model, Funcionario funcionario, Usuario usuario, BindingResult result){
    ///METODO///
}
```

}

Estou utilizando JSP

Busquei soluções em outros tópicos, mas nenhum resolveu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente especificar o tipo de requisição: Post, Get, etc. No seu caso acredito que seja um Post, então o método ficaria assim:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/funcionarios")
    public class ManterFuncionarioController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/criar")
        public String criarFuncionario(Model model, Funcionario funcionario, Usuario usuario, BindingResult result){
        ///METODO///
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima para salvar terá que acessar http://localhost:8080/funcionarios/criar e especificar sua requisição como Post.

Comment: eu resolvi retirando alguns parâmetros do meu método Controller, provavelmente alguma erro no mapeamento da JSP para o Controller que esta incorreto.